# Python Number Processed Per Hour

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was able to get this working in excel, however I can't seem to find the solution for Python 3.X. How do I calculate the number processed per hour?

I need to create a formula that will determine the number of units produced in 1 hour. The formula `unitsPerHour =  totalProcessed/(totalTime*24)` works in excel, but not in Python. It seems as though `totalTime*24` always produces `0`.

Example: Spent 4 hours and 26 minutes and 3 seconds (04:26:03) and completed 73 units. How many units were completed per hour?

```
# "%d:%d:%d" % (diff.hours, diff.minutes, diff.seconds) = 04:26:03
totalTime = "%d:%d:%d" % (diff.hours, diff.minutes, diff.seconds)
totalProcessed = 73
denomCheck = totalTime*24
if denomCheck != 0:
    unitsPerHour =  totalProcessed/(totalTime*24)
```

Of course, an error is thrown whenever the denominator is equal to zero. Which is the purpose of the denomCheck variable. I do have instances where totalTime is equal to zero, so I have to check for it.

Comment: You're multiplying a string and a number (`"4:26:3" * 24`). In Python, that repeats the string. Then you're dividing a number by that long string. This should produce an error that says you can't divide an `int` (number) by a `str` (string).

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, you never converted your `diff` variable from the triple of values to a *numeric* quantity of hours.  Instead, you formatted it as a human-readable string.  Multiply a string by 24 gives you 24 copies concatenated into one string ... which you *should* have verified with a simple `print` statement before posting.  For instance:

```
# "%d:%d:%d" % (diff.hours, diff.minutes, diff.seconds) = 04:26:03
totalTime = "%d:%d:%d" % (4, 26, 3)
totalProcessed = 73
denomCheck = totalTime*24
print "totalTime", totalTime
print "denomCheck", denomCheck
if denomCheck != 0:
    unitsPerHour =  totalProcessed/(totalTime*24)
```

Output:

```
totalTime 4:26:3
denomCheck 4:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:34:26:3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 8, in <module>
    unitsPerHour =  totalProcessed/(totalTime*24)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

SOLUTION:

Do the math:

```
total_time = diff.hours + diff.minutes/60.0 + diff.seconds/3600.0
```

If you want to learn to manipulate a data type that makes these things easier, try Python's `datetime` package.

Answer (score 0):

Given a string like '04:26:03', you can do the following to calculate units per hour:

```
time_string = '04:26:03'

# extract hours, minutes, and seconds
hours, minutes, seconds =  [int(item.lstrip('0')) for item in time_string.split(':')]

# calculate total time, assuming Python 3
total_time_in_hours = hours + minutes/60 + seconds/3600

# units per hour
units_per_hour = totalProcessed / total_time_in_hours
```

If the values are available as integers,
simply do:

```
total_time_in_hours = diff.hours + diff.minutes / 60 + diff.seconds / 3600
units_per_hour = totalProcessed / total_time_in_hours
```